# AFNetworking requests got timeout too early in very bad network condition

Tags: ios, timeout, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm using AFNetworking 2.5 and everything was fine until I had a very bad network problem. My requests were getting random timeouts:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60
```

So, as I was sending images, I wanted to increase the timeout delay by using the:

```
aRequestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 600; // 10 minutes
```

Unfortunately, the request gets a timeout after very various delays: 30 seconds, 2 minutes, 3 minutes and a half, 6 minutes... But it never stops at 10 minutes.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[self setupAuthTokenForRequestSerializer:manager.requestSerializer];
[self setupAuthHeaderForRequestSerializer:manager.requestSerializer];
[self setupTimeoutForRequestSerializer:manager.requestSerializer];

return [manager POST:aUrl 
          parameters:nil 
constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
             [formData appendPartWithFileData:aImageData
                                         name:@"file"
                                     fileName:@"file.jpg"
                                     mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
         }
             success:successBlock 
             failure:failureBlock];
```

**Edit**: The problem occurs as well on iOS 7 and 8, on real devices and simulator...

**Edit 2**: It looks like that the resulting operation's request has a timeoutInterval only of 60... (it still does not explain why this random timeout)

**Edit 3**: It seems that `AFHTTPRequestSerializer`'s KVO to update `NSMutableURLRequest` timeoutInterval does not work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to this chunk of code: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/0f3829f6afdfa57eced1e80c317e68ca5e5f85d0#comments

When removed, the requests lasts much longer... even more than 10 minutes, perhaps it is because of the cpu time, and not real time... I don't know. Anyway, it seems to be solved...